# Mapbox show location Paris

Tags: nativescript, mapbox, mapbox-android

I get correctly coordinate from this function in Map.ts:

```
populateForm() {
    let pharmaId = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.pharma.pharmagetbyid(pharmaId ).subscribe(
        pharmadata=> {
          if (pharmadata){
            this.pharmadata= pharmadata;
          }
        }
    );
}
```

In html I write this code in Map.html:

```
 <Mapbox
      accessToken="pk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      mapStyle="traffic_day"
      [latitude]="pharmadata.latitude"
      [longitude]="pharmadata.longitude"
      zoomLevel="7"
      delay="450"
      showUserLocation="true"
      hideCompass="false"
      disableZoom="false"
      disableRotation="false"
      disableScroll="false"
      disableTilt="false"
      (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
  </Mapbox>
```

And this onMapReady() have this code in Map.ts:

```
 onMapReady(args): void {
    this.map = args.map;
    console.log(args.map)
    this.map.addMarkers([
          {
            lat: this.pharmadata.longitude,
            lng: this.pharmadata.latitude,
          }
        ]
    );
  }
```

My coordinate are:

> "longitude": 4.56, "latitude": 5.65

In map show [firstly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzLLs.jpg) 
and when I zoom map show [Marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtAOq.jpg)

Can you suggest me any idea how to show only Marks?

Comment: You will have to adjust the map camera to focus on the desired location, the solution is already discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/106)

Answer (score 0):

Your lat/long are flipped in your `onMapReady` function. Your code should look like this:

```
 onMapReady(args): void {
    this.map = args.map;
    console.log(args.map)
    this.map.addMarkers([
          {
            lat: this.pharmadata.latitude, // Flip these
            lng: this.pharmadata.longitude, // two lines
          }
        ]
    );
  }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in .html  not in ts

Comment: Did you try flipping the coordinates in your function? My guess is it's backward since Mapbox coordinates are `lng/lat` instead of `lat/lng`